# JavaScript to Applet call freezes the chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am using javascript to applet communication to do some processing in my current project. The processing done in the applet is little heavy, whenever applet is processing the request, Browser freezes and user is not able to work with browser anymore. from applet i am trying to update browser with log messages about request processing using jsobject.getWindow(x,y) api but in chrome messages are not updated where as firefox it does.

Basically browser window is not able to refresh its contents and appears to be freeze to the user while the applet is processing the request.

Any solution/workaround to this problem?

Thanks,